# Memory cast for WebView

Tags: android, webview, bitmap

Why do WebView cast so small memory to show a bitmap ?

Here is a bitmap, which is 3000 * 2077 in size.

```
http://img.bz1111.com/d7/2012-8/2012081210376.jpg
```

When I show it in ImageView, It cast more than 20MB memory to show it(I think bitmap  decodes with ARGB_8888).

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    mImageView = imageView;

    setContentView(imageView);

    new LoadImageTask().execute("http://img.bz1111.com/d7/2012-8/2012081210376.jpg");
}

private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(params[0]).openStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

While, in WebView, it cast just 40KB:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private static final String HTML_WITH_IMAGE = "<html>" +
        "<head></head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<img src=\"%s\" />" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";

private static final String HTML_WITHOUT_IMAGE = "<html>" +
        "<head></head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<span>Empty</span>" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // create WebView;
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");//http://img.bz1111.com/d7/2012-8/2012081210376.jpg
    String html = null;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        html = HTML_WITHOUT_IMAGE;
    } else {
        html = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, HTML_WITH_IMAGE, imageUrl);
    }

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.google.com",
            html,
            "text/html",
            "utf-8",
            "");
}
```

I want to know, How WebView( or WebKit) to decode the bitmap, and save the bitmap to draw ?

Comment: Well, I have got it.

Comment: I use Memory Monitor in Android Studio which only monitor dalvik heap for java. On the other hand, Webkit work in native heap to decode and draw bitmap.